# Trying to zoom on image inside a 240*240 div

Tags: html, css, image

I need help with some code, I am trying to make an image basically zoom in within 240px by 240px div, I don't know how exactly how to explain it, but basically the image needs to be zoomed in on and only in a certain square area.

the first one here is fine, doesn't need anything changed, but the second one doesn't fit within the whole square because it is too small.

```
    <!-- 2 --><a class="wsb-media-carousel-wrapper img_rounded_corners" rel="wsb-media-carousel-desktop" href="productimg/bowk-inside.jfif" data-fancybox-type="image" style="height: 240px; width: 240px; margin: 20px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;"><img src="productimg/bowl-inside.jfif" style="width: 240px; top: -39.2138px;"></a>
```

here is how it looks: i want the second one to look like the second one without actually resizing the image out of the code. i got this code from another website but cannot figure out how they made it fit.

my website: [my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUa0u.png)
their website: [their website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISjSh.png)

Comment: If your image is smaller than 240 then you need a new image or else it will be pixelated

Comment: For the second one you can define `height:100%;`

Answer (score 0):

The style attribute `object-fit` specifies how elements such as images should be placed inside of it's container. You can learn about it at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

I have created a basic example of `object-fit` set to `cover` on a series of images to create the effect you are looking for.

```css
img {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

img.orig {
  object-fit: initial;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>Original Images</p>
<img class='orig' src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/221014/hub-default.jpg" alt="">
<img class='orig' src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/221014/background1.jpg" alt="">
<hr>
<p>Object-fit images</p>
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/221014/hub-default.jpg" alt="">
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/221014/background1.jpg" alt="">
```